# Ошибка 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess

Сайт на yii2 kit-starter, перенес его на поддомен, но стал выдавать ошибку:

> **Internal Server Error**
>   The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@perevozkishop.ru
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (@RELEASE@) Server at test.perevozkishop.ru Port 80

Когда удаляю htaccess, то все работает, код htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ frontend/web/favicon.ico [L]

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^backend(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^storage(/(.*))?$ storage/web/$2 [L]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* frontend/web

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Скиньте логи ошибок apache

Comment: перенесли на поддомен, в смысле сайт остался физически на том же сервере с теми же настройками?

Comment: да остался на том же сервере

Comment: ошибок нет в логах

Comment: поменял htaccess, заработала главная, но при переходе на другие страницы выдает ту же ошибку